# filter file list on basis of file type in mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

For my android application which is being developed using phonegap cordova 2.5.0, I need to apply filter on a file list on the basis of their types (like audio, video, documents, exe etc). I have used data-filter but that gives a search option. What I need is to sort the files of a kind.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `phonegap` to get all file names and then just filter them with `regex`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have obtained your array of files by calling `.listFiles()`, you can run a few sorting algorithms on it.

Start by parsing the extensions by using `.split(String str, String sep)` which will return an array in which the elements are the substrings that would be separated by the value of 'sep'. Take the last element, this is your file extension.

You should have some idea of what file extensions you support, so make a `Map<String,String>` that will map a file extension, to the type of file it is. Then you can run through your list of files, parse out the extensions, lookup the type from the map, and do with it what you will.